# Expand Collapse divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sass

I have different divs, I want to click on a div and expand its content, and if I click again it should hide that content, that is working fine, but I have different divs, and I want only one div expanded at the same time, how should I reach this?

This it's not good, do you see at this time I can have several divs expanded, how can I make sure that this won't happen?:
[image]

This is what I want to reach:
[image]

JQuery function, how can I collapse any other expanded div when I click in a new one?:

```
  $(".contact_item .head").click(function () {
            if ($(this).parent('div').hasClass('expanded')) {
                $(this).next('div').slideUp();
                $(this).parent('div').removeClass('expanded');
            } else {
                $(this).parent('div').addClass('expanded');
                $(this).next('div').slideDown();
            }
        });
```

Html code:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"> </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 white">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 rghtpd"><style>.rghtpd{padding-right: 0px !important; width:583px;}</style>
                            <div class="title">Contact us</div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                                                                                                                    <div class="contact_item expanded">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">California office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: block;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        One Embarcadero Center Suite 500, San Fransisco, 94111, CA
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (415) 639-3001
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">Florida office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: none;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        9600 Koger Blvd. Suite 225, St. Petersburg, 33702, FL
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (727) 578-2800
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">London office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: none;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        Lloyd's Building, Gallery 4 12 Leadenhall St., London, EC3V 1LP, England
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (0207) 101-9395
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item ">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">myName office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        123 Fake st , Springfield, 12345, OH
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        555
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="contact_item expanded">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">Ohio office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: block;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        4449 Easton Way 2nd Floor, Columbus, 43219, OH
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (614)526-8754
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">Pennsylvania office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: none;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        One International Plaza Suite 550, Philadelphia, 19113, PA
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (215) 279-5845
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item ">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">Texas office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        950 Echo Lane Suite 200, Houston, 77024, TX
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (832) 586-0301
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item ">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">WASH office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        1100 Dexter Avenue North Suite 100, Seattle, 98109, WA
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (253)271-9692
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

**UPDATE: This is the CSS**

```
 .contact_item {
        width: 100%;
        border: 1px solid #f1e7e0;
        background-color: #fcf6f5;
        margin: 3px 0px;
        float: left;

        &.expanded {
            .head .name {
                color: #f60;
            }

            .head .name span {
                border-color: #f60;
                color: #f60;

                &.plus {
                    display: none;
                }

                &.minus {
                    display: block;
                }
            }
        }

        .head {
            .name {
                font-family: "Tahoma";
                color: rgb(100, 100, 100);
                font-size: 11.1px;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                padding: 7px 15px;
                cursor: pointer;
                position: relative;

                span {
                    position: absolute;
                    display: block;
                    width: 20px;
                    height: 20px;
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    border: 1px solid #706f6f;
                    text-align: center;
                    right: 15px;
                    top: 7px;
                    font-size: 18px;
                    line-height: 17px;

                    &.minus {
                        display: none;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've changed a little bit my JQuery function and now it allows just one div expanded, but I have to click twice to expand a div, the first time it closes any other expanded div but doesn't open the one that I clicked on, and the second time then is opened:

```
  $(".contact_item .head").click(function () {            
            if ($(".contact_item .head").parent('div').hasClass('expanded')) {
                $(".contact_item .head").next('div').slideUp();
                $(".contact_item .head").parent('div').removeClass('expanded');

            } else {
                $(this).parent('div').addClass('expanded');
                $(this).next('div').slideDown();
            }
        });
```

Comment: (unrelated to the problem) You missed the address for the Ohio office when censoring the second exemple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those were nice suggestions but didn't work completely, finally this is what I did with my function and now it works:

```
 $(".contact_item .head").click(function () {
            var flag = $(this).parent('div').hasClass('expanded');            
            if ($(".contact_item .head").parent('div').hasClass('expanded')) {
                $(".contact_item .head").next('div').slideUp();
                $(".contact_item .head").parent('div').removeClass('expanded');                 
                if (flag==false) {
                    $(this).parent('div').addClass('expanded');
                    $(this).next('div').slideDown();
                }
            }           
            else {
                $(this).parent('div').addClass('expanded');
                $(this).next('div').slideDown();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement your requirement:

https://jsfiddle.net/pje7Lznf/

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3"> </div>
                <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 white">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 col-xs-12 rghtpd"><style>.rghtpd{padding-right: 0px !important; width:583px;}</style>
                            <div class="title">Contact us</div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                                                                                                                                    <div class="contact_item expanded">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">California office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: block;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        One Embarcadero Center Suite 500, San Fransisco, 94111, CA
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (415) 639-3001
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">Florida office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: none;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        9600 Koger Blvd. Suite 225, St. Petersburg, 33702, FL
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (727) 578-2800
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">London office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: none;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        Lloyd's Building, Gallery 4 12 Leadenhall St., London, EC3V 1LP, England
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (0207) 101-9395
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item ">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">myName office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        123 Fake st , Springfield, 12345, OH
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        555
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="contact_item expanded">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">Ohio office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: block;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        4449 Easton Way 2nd Floor, Columbus, 43219, OH
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (614)526-8754
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">Pennsylvania office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info" style="display: none;">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        One International Plaza Suite 550, Philadelphia, 19113, PA
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (215) 279-5845
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item ">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">Texas office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        950 Echo Lane Suite 200, Houston, 77024, TX
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (832) 586-0301
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="contact_item ">
                                            <div class="head">
                                                <div class="name">WASH office<span class="plus">+</span> <span class="minus">-</span></div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="info">
                                                <ul>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/marker.png"></div>
                                                        1100 Dexter Avenue North Suite 100, Seattle, 98109, WA
                                                    </li>
                                                    <li>
                                                        <div class="icon"><img alt="" src="//lig.azureedge.net/public/UK/Content/Images/phone.png"></div>
                                                        (253)271-9692
                                                    </li>
                                                </ul>
                                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

$(".contact_item .head").click(function () {

            if ($(this).parent('div').hasClass('expanded')) {
                $(this).next('div').slideUp();
                $(this).parent('div').removeClass('expanded');
                $(".info").each(function(i , obj){
                    console.log($(obj))
                  $(obj).removeClass('expanded');
                  $(obj).slideUp();
                })
            } else {
                 $(".info").each(function(i , obj){
                    console.log($(obj))
                  $(obj).removeClass('expanded');
                  $(obj).slideUp();
                })
                $(this).parent('div').addClass('expanded');
                $(this).next('div').slideDown();
            }


        });

.contact_item{
  background-color: #bdc3c7;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I put together a fiddle with a simple CSS-based solution that allows the jQuery code to be boiled down to something like this:

```
 $('.contact_item').on('click', '.head', function () {
   var clicked = $(this).closest('.contact_item');
   $('.contact_item.expanded').add(clicked).toggleClass('expanded');
 });
```

The solution does away with animations, but it's how I've been handling a lot of these types of situations and it is super clean comparatively.  It should be a fairly simple exercise from here to add the animations back in if necessary, but consider this solution as a nice alternative:

[Fiddle w/ solution](https://jsfiddle.net/6y4ggg1L/)